# How to listen to messages from an MQ using Spring 4's JmsTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, message-queue

Working with WebSphere MQ in a Spring 4 application and having some trouble with *listening* to the MQ (sending messages works just fine).

Here is a piece of my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file where I specify my information for my `JmsTemplate`:

```
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="appJmsConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="MQ.LISTENER.INFO.HERE" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Here is my listener class:

```
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringJmsConsumer {
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private Destination destination;

    public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate() {
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public Destination getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(Destination destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public String receiveMessage() throws JMSException {
        Message message = jmsTemplate.receive(jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestination());
        // TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)
        // jmsTemplate.receive(destination);
        System.out.println("The message listened is: " + message.toString());
        return message.toString();
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: JMSMQ0003: The destination is not understood or no longer valid.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSMQ0003: The destination is not understood or no longer valid. The queue or topic might have become unavailable, the application might be using an incorrect connection for the queue or topic, or the supplied destination is not of the correct type for this method.
```

I have performed research on how to solve this issue, but unable to arrive at a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out a while ago but figured I would post the answer here to help anyone else out in the future.

When using Spring's JMS functionality, the listener needs to be annotated with `@JmsListener`

With that being said here is the updated function of `receiveMessage()`:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "MQ.LISTENER.INFO.HERE")
    public String receiveMessage(String text) throws JMSException {
        LOGGER.info("Received something!");
        this.jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert("MQ.LISTENER.INFO.HERE");
        LOGGER.info("Received message from MQ.LISTENER.INFO.HERE: ");
        return "Acknowledgement from receiveMessage";
    }
```

Keep in mind it is a callback function!